# Fujitsu iRMC S4 Web Server Unable to Access

Tags: ssl, cipher

I have a Fujitsu TX140 S2 server hosting a number of drives.

Recently went to log into the iRMC web server to turn the server off during the high winds in case of a power cut (UPS on order) and couldn't access the web server.

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

I thought it was a browser issue so installed Version 1 of Firefox and was able to get into the fujitsu web server from that so it's clearly a browser issue but that is outside of my remit.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is old, and the TLS/SSL versions used at the time of the release is not supported by modern browser, as the TLS/SSL protocols [have severe security problems.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE)

You can try to [upgrade the iRMC firmware](https://support.ts.fujitsu.com/IndexDownload.asp?Softwareguid=CB2C4EEB-DB82-4280-A097-12CFD2ECE426) on it. The linked download is a Windows download, but you'll find others from Fujitsus support pages.

Ultimately, given that this is a old system, you may forced to use old software to access iRMC on it. I could find no information on support of modern TLS standards across different iRMC revisions.

Comment: That is a good point, the firmware is currently version 7.68F. I believe TLS v1.3 is 2018? so that's likely the issue.

Comment: It *is* the issue, but the question is if it's possible to fix. To verify, can use `openssl s_client -connect host.example.com` which will print TLS protocol and cipher.

Comment: That did it. Updated the iRMC firmware with v9.21 first which brought back access via a modern browser now, and now updating to v9.6 (as that was the recommended stepping)

Comment: That's great :)